# Launch/raise application and cycle through its windows using AppleScript and keyboard shortcut

Tags: applescript, cycle, launch, automator

How can I use AppleScript to create a keyboard shortcut which will:

- Launch an application if it's not running.
- Bring the application to the foreground if it is running.
- Cycle through ***only the application's*** windows if I keep pressing the shortcut keys.

For example, when I press Option-Y, it will launch Terminal or bring it to the foreground, and if I keep pressing Option-Y it will cycle through the multiple open Terminal windows if I have more than one open.

I have successfully created an AppleScript using Automator as a service.  I have successfully mapped this script to a keyboard shortcut by going to System Preferences, Keyboard, Shortcuts, Services and under General, checking and assigning a keyboard shortcut to the Automator service BringTerminalToTheForeground.

Here is the script to launch the Terminal:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
end tell
```

I want to do this only with the tools which come with the Mac by default (e.g. AppleScript, Automator).  I'm running El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Command-"`" will cycle through an application's windows.

```
tell application "Terminal" -- try other applications. This script might work in other cases. It happens to work with Terminal but I haven't tested it.
    activate
    set c to count of windows -- we need to know how many windows the application has so we only cycle through all of them once.
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat c times
            keystroke "`" using command down --  this is what cycles through the windows. This doesn't work in every application.
            delay 1 -- this is a 1-second delay. Change this to whatever delay you want.
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly what you are asking for, but I'm using [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/), [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) and [GokuRakuJoudo](https://github.com/yqrashawn/GokuRakuJoudo) (optional but highly recommended).

First you have to create this lua module using Hammerspoon https://github.com/fabiomcosta/keyboard/blob/73b22906b31dfc12cc834c382515e30c4450d0f5/hammerspoon/hyper.lua#L76 then on my karabiner.edn (using Goku) I define a keymapping calling that function using Hammespoon's cli `hs`.

It's not easy to setup and in fact that's why I'm looking for a new way to achieve the same behavior without this much setup haha.
But it definitely works.